# Different Ways to Query Custom Post Types?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, query-posts, query

I'm using this code to use custom post types like regular post:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_post_types_to_query' );

function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'miss_behave', 'emily_davies','gemma_patel','poppy_smythe' ) );
return $query;
}
```

But I also saw this code to display custom post types:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page', 'movie', 'book' )
) );
```

I'm wondering what the differences are between the two methods.

Thanks.

Comment: Go and check out this [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts) and this [anwer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts). This will definitly shed some light on your question

Comment: This [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50762/170) is your answer, maybe you use the search before you ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first way, using the pre_get_posts action will modify the main query before the page loads.  The second way will create a new query.  It is much better to alter the main query than to create a new query.

Answer (score 0):

**pre_get_posts**

`pre_get_posts` is used to alter the main query for posts so the `is_home()` conditional tag will work.

You can also use the is_post_type_archive() conditional tag to alter the query on CPT archives like so.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'limit_cpt_items' );
function limit_cpt_items( $query ) {

if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_post_type_archive( 'your-cpt' ) ) {
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '24' );
    }

}
```

**WP_Query**

You would use a new WP_Query for page requests including conditional tags for pages like `is_page()`, `is_page_template()` and `is_front_page()` which will NOT work with pre_get_posts which is runs before WP_Query.